# Creating a function that takes scores as parameters that outputs to a print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question I was asking was - This function will take the list of players and the list of scores as parameters and will output the contents of the lists to the screen. This function displays the information to the screen in the format specified in the assignment specifications under the section - 'Screen Format'. You must use a loop in your solution.

In which the list is in another text file - players.txt which contents are:

```
Ray Holt
15
Jessica Jones
0
Johnny Rose
10
Gina Linetti
6
Alexis Rose
1
Buster Bluth
3
```

which must include a list function so it can be displayed like this:

```
====================================
- Player Summary -
====================================
- Name Score -
------------------------------------
- Ray Holt 15 -
------------------------------------
- Jessica Jones 0 -
------------------------------------
- Johnny Rose 10 -
------------------------------------
- Gina Linetti 6 -
------------------------------------
- Alexis Rose 1 -
------------------------------------
- Buster Bluth 3 -
------------------------------------
====================================
```

Code is to be written in this format:

```
# Function display_players() - place your own comments here...  : )
def display_players(player_list, score_list):

    # This line will eventually be removed - used for development purposes only.
    print("In function display_players()")

    # Place your code here
```

Not sure how to place it in, any pointers would be great!

Edit - Cant use inbuilt functions such as len

Answer (score 0):

If both lists have the same length, you can iterate over it like this:

```
# Function display_players() - place your own comments here...  : )
def display_players(player_list, score_list):
    print('- Player Summary -')
    for i in len(player_list):
        print(f"- {player_list[i]} {score_list[i]}")
```

Comment: Sadly the assignment doesn't  let me use inbuilt functions - should've clarified that sorry

Comment: @Wella you should indeed have clarified that ! But wait - that would mean you can't output anything - `print` is a buitlin ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Typical use-case for the builtin `zip(iterable1, iterable2)` - it has the advantage of not raising an `IndexError` when one of the lists is shorter than the other. To get the horizontal lines from equal and minus signs, you don't need to write the whole line - you can use string multiplication here:

```py
def display_players(player_list, score_list):
    print("=" * 36)
    print("- Player Summary -")
    print("=" * 36)
    count = 0
    for player in player_list:
        score = score_list[count]
        print(f"- {player} {score} -")
        print("-" * 36)
        count += 1
    print("=" * 36)

def test():
    with open("players.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    players = []
    scores = []
    
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip() # remove trailing and leading spaces
        if line: # if the string line is not empty …
            if line.isdigit(): # … and the string consists only of numbers …
                scores.append(int(line)) # convert it to int and append it to scores …
            else: # if there are alphabetical letters in the string, append it to players
                players.append(line)
    display_players(players, scores)
```

Comment: Ahh Okay, another question is how would I use the players.txt within that function to print out all those names within the text file?

Comment: @Wella I don't understand your last comment - do you mean how to read the players.txt file in a string ?

Comment: Ah sorry! I'm still quite new to stack and python - but what I'm trying to express is, when I use the function display_players how would the names from the text file print to the screen if that makes sense?

Comment: @Wella the player names and scores are given to the function as arguments, then printed out with the `print` function - you do not need to bother about how to open the players.txt file, separate players and scores - when your code is tested, the tester will do all that, and just pass your function two lists - one containing player names, and one containing player scores. I will add a function that reads the file and converts it to a list for testing purposes, though.

Comment: Thanks legend, is there any way I can contact you for help with the rest of the assignment I have - it's kind of doing my head in!

Comment: @Wella you can always send me an email or ask a new question - but I dont look at my emails more than once a day !

Comment: Ah damn! Sadly reached my question limit, and me being me once again this due quite soon. Thank you very much for the help though!

Comment: @Wella well, there is no email limit ! You can write to `programmer.anonymous@yandex.com` if you need my help.

Comment: Flicked you an email!